# How do I convert a java.sql.Date object into a GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I thought I'd be able to create a [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) using the constructor that takes the year, month, and day, but I can't reliably get those fields from an instance of the [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class.  The methods that get those values from `java.sql.Date` are deprecated, and the following code shows why they can't be used:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = Date.valueOf("2011-12-25");
        System.out.println("Year: " + date.getYear());
        System.out.println("Month: " + date.getMonth());
        System.out.println("Day: " + date.getDate());
        System.out.println(date);

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

Here's the output, showing that the month and year are not returned correctly from the deprecated `getYear()` and `getMonth()` methods of `Date`:

> Year: 111
>   Month: 11
>   Day: 25
>   2011-12-25
>   Thu Dec 25 00:00:00 EST 111

Since I can't use the constructor that I tried above, and there's no `GregorianCalendar` constructor that just takes a `Date`, how can I convert a `java.sql.Date` object into a `GregorianCalendar`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to do this in two steps.  First create a `GregorianCalendar` using the default constructor, then set the date using the (confusingly named) [`setTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) method.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = Date.valueOf("2011-12-25");
        System.out.println(date);

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

> 2011-12-25
>   Sun Dec 25 00:00:00 EST 2011

Answer (score 4):

I'm going from memory, but have you tried

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(rs.getDate());
```

Comment: From where rs.getDate() came from?

Comment: sorry - rs is the variable name I always give to ResultSet objects - it's just there to represent a java.sql.Date instance that you have already instantiated.

Comment: Not really the most specific answer, but +1 for following some standards that made this the exact code I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = Date.valueOf("2011-12-25");
        System.out.println(date);

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [setTimeInMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29):

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
```

I think this is the simplest way.